# LED illumination in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios6, led

Can anyone show me an example of how to use the following method:

```
 (BOOL)setTorchModeOnWithLevel:(float)torchLevel error:(NSError **)outError
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant. Read the faq please.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Apple's reference here: [AVCaptureDevice](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

First import AVFoundation and [add it to the build phases.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH17-SW1)

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

Then use following code:

```
//Get all devices (front and back camera)
for (AVCaptureDevice *device in [AVCaptureDevice devices]) {

    if ([device position] != AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) {
        NSLog(@"This is the front camera");
        continue; // go to next device
    }

    NSLog(@"This is the back camera");

    if([device hasTorch] == NO){
        NSLog(@"this camera has no torch...");
        continue; // go to next device
    }

    NSLog(@"The camera has a torch");

    if([device isTorchAvailable] == NO){
        NSLog(@"The torch is not available...");
        continue; // go to next device
    }

    NSLog(@"The torch is available");

    //get device dependent maximum (between 0 and 1)
    float level = AVCaptureMaxAvailableTorchLevel;

    NSError* outError;
    BOOL success = [device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:level error:&outError];

    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Could not activate torch: %@", [outError localizedDescription]);
        continue; // go to next device
    }

    NSLog(@"The torch is now active!");
}
```